# Wowza permissions for source authentication

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, wowza

I want to give permissions to publishers so that they can't stream to all live applications on wowza server. With default configuration, publishers can stream all live applications on wowza server.

Let's say there are 3 publishers: publisher1, publisher2, publisher3 and 3 live applications: liveapp1, liveapp2, liveapp3. I want to make each publishers can stream only their application like below:

```
publisher1 => liveapp1
publisher2 => liveapp2
publisher3 => liveapp3
```

I tried giving user names to clientStreamWriteAccess parameter in Application.xml of related live application. But it didn't work. Normally, value of this parameter is "*".

Is there any way to make this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to setup different "publish.password" files for each application.

> Each time you setup an application create the file
>   [install-dir]/conf/[application]/publish.password file to store the
>   username and passwords for that application.

Check [this](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?159-How-to-use-a-per-application-publish-password-file) out for detailed instructions.